# How can i update an element in collection instead of the reference

Tags: c#

I have a collection ProductSearchResults, below method intends to find a specific product in that collection and update it. I end up updating the object that points to the element of the collection instead of the actual element it self though(i think)

Can you please show me how to do this properly so that I update the actual product in the collection

Thanks

```
public void UpdateProductInfo(ProductInfo product)
    {
        var productToUpdate = this.ProductSearchResults.Where(p => p.ID == product.ID);

        if (productUpdate.Count() > 0)
        {
            var toUpdate = productToUpdate.First<ProductInfo>();

            toUpdate = product;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's best to get into the habit of using productUpdate.Any() instead of productUpdate.Count() > 0 just in case the collection you're dealing with doesn't implement ICollection (in which case it'd use the Count property). If it's an IEnumerable, Count() will enumerate the entire collection whereas productUpdate.Any() just calls MoveNext() which returns true if there is at least one item in the collection.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

IN actual fact all you are doing is changing the reference to the local variable `toUpdate` to point at the passed-in argument `product`.

Lets take a step backwards, when you do:

```
var toUpdate = productToUpdate.First<ProductInfo>();
```

you have a *reference* to an item from your collection (`ProductSearchResults`). You can now happily update its properties, ala:

```
toUpdate.ProductName = product.ProductName;
toUpdate.Price = product.Price;
//etc..
```

however, you cannot update the itemn in the collection to point to a different/new item in the way you were attempting to. You could remove that item from the collection, and add your new one if that is indeed what you require:

```
public void UpdateProductInfo(ProductInfo product)
    {
        var productToUpdate = this.ProductSearchResults.Where(p => p.ID == product.ID);

        if (productUpdate.Count() > 0)
        {
            var toUpdate = productToUpdate.First<ProductInfo>();

            this.ProductSearchResults.Remove(toUpdate);
            this.ProductSearchResults.Add(product);
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Where will return an IEnumerable<ProductInfo> which doesn't have Add or Remove methods. Creating a List from it will create a new list so that won't work. If ProductSearchResults is a List<ProductInfo> you can use Find and then Remove and Add.

Answer (score 3):

```
var productToUpdate = this.ProductSearchResults.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == product.ID);

if (productUpdate != null)
{
    productUpdate.Property = product.Property;
    ...continue for other properties
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, writing `variable = expression;` assigns a new value to the variable. It does not affect the value that was previously referenced by that variable.

In your example, you have a value called `product`, which is a `ProductInfo` provided by the caller, and a value you get from your list, which you stored in `toUpdate`, that you wish to **update**. This would involve calling member functions (or assigning to properties) of `toUpdate` based on values in `product`.

However, I suspect you actually want to update the product information of a product found in a database or other kind of storage that is accessed by `ProductSearchResults`. The storage engine you use (or your data access layer) probably provides you with a function to save a `ProductInfo` associated with a certain identifier, so all you need to do is call that function.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to replace the product in the collection or update some properties on it? Assuming the latter, here's an example:

```
public void UpdateProductInfo(ProductInfo product)
{
    var productToUpdate = this.ProductSearchResults.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == product.ID).;
    if (productToUpdate == null)
    {
        // throw exception?
    }
    else
    {
        productToUpdate.Price = productInfo.Price; // for example
    }
}
```